# Batch set with merge option

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a batch method corresponding to the javascript set with merge option?

I was looking at the documents, but couldn't find anything on this. If not, what is the current official approach to merging items in a batch?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After some time, I found out that you can achive that using:

```
batch.set(db.doc(t.ref.toString()), { field: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete() }, { merge: true }))
```

Comment: Good job on finding this. Could you provide the source?

Comment: @zavtra, I cannot recall now - it was long ago. Just thought about updating the answer :)

Comment: Link to docs for batch.set: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#set

Comment: this worked for me:- 
batch.set(documentReference,mapOf(field to true),SetOptions.merge())

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python just use:
`batch.set("path/to/document", data, merge=True)`

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) - addition of data says that we can add a parameter "merge=True" for setting with merge.
The same applies to batch updates and works fine when tested on Python3.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The other answer with a dict as the third parameter does not work, at least on the current version of Firestore libs.

Comment: Your answer is about Python. The question is about the equivalent way to use `set` on a `batch` reference as when using `set` on a single document reference in Javascript. In Javascript, you do need to pass `{merge=true}` as the options object as the third parameter.

Comment: {merge: true} is correct in Javascript, isn't it?